# Cumulocity Data Types Handling

Tags: iot, cumulocity

How does one handle different data types in the Cumulocity IoT Cloud? Things like:
Double - Double precision floating-point value in accordance to IEEE754
Float - Single precision floating-point value in accordance to IEEE754
Decimal - Decimal with arbitrary precision
Long - Signed 64bit integer value
Int - Signed 32bit integer value
Short - Signed 16bit integer value
Byte - Signed 8bit integer value

Answer (score 0):

Cumulocity attempts to preserve the data it is presented with, up to what it can fit in 64-bits. If it receive an integer which can fit in 32 bits C8Y will store it that way, similarly if it's an integer which is too big for 32 bits but fits in 64 bits then it is stored as a 64-bit integer. Otherwise an IEEE 754 64-bit binary float is used.
Some reference to the docs:
https://cumulocity.com/guides/reference/measurements/#measurement
v10.6.0